# How to properly set a debounce in a react hook?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a simple component that is supposed to act as an autosuggest. I based my component on [this article](https://dev.to/danilo95/react-autocomplete-search-input-debounce-2mof). Unfortunately, it seems like my component is still firing requests like crazy, and I have no idea why. Here's the actual code of the hook I'm using inside of my component: (The component itself is just an input which uses the returned `onChange`)

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');  

const debounceFetchCompanies = useCallback(
    debounce((value: string) => {
      if (value.trim().length >= 3) {
        refetchEnrichedCompanies({
          name: value.trim(),
        });
      }
    }, 500),
    [refetchEnrichedCompanies, dataEnrichedCompanies],
  );

const handleChange = useCallback(
    (value: string) => {
      setInputValue(value);
      debounceFetchCompanies(value);
    },
    [debounceFetchCompanies],
  );
```

When checking inside my network tab in Chrome inspector, I see a request being sent on every single new character.

Comment: And the debounce fn you are using is the one of `lodash`?

Comment: yes. I also thought about using `throttle` from lodash, but same result